# Gulp-template проблема

Tags: javascript, gulp

Всем здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой при работе с gulp-tamplate.
Имею такой код в gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const template = require('gulp-template');

gulp.task('default', () =>
    gulp.src('src/js/main.js')
        .pipe(template({ojs: '*'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
);
```

Main.js состоит с условия,

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
   <%= ojs %>
}
```

Возможно вставить .pipe(template({ojs: '*'})), место *, ссылку на js файл с которого оно будет брать сам код?

---

Мой код из gulp

```
   gulp.task('default', function() {
        return gulp.src('./src/jQ_pre.js')
            .pipe(data(() => ({ codejs : gulp.src(jq)})))
            .pipe(concat('jq.js'))
            .pipe(template())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
    });
```

Вот что имею на выходе,

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
    [object Object]
}
```

Не может считать код файла, как можно пофиксить?